# Re-map scancode -> keycode of MacBook Pro built-in keyboard

Tags: systemd, udev, keyboard-layout, macintosh

## Object

I read [this Arch wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes) to try to remap scancode & keycode on my Chakra 201710 + MacBook Pro 2015 (no touchbar and USB-C):

1. Remap the **built-in keyboard** of like this:

   ```
   | ORIGINAL || capslock | control | option(alt) | command(meta?) |
   | MAP TO   || ctrl     | ctrl    | super       | alt            |
   ```
2. **Don't remap other external USB keyboard.** (I never use an Apple external keyboard).

## What I have tried (but failed, not works.)

### 1. Find the vendor id / product id / version of build-in keyboard

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/hwdb/60-keyboard.hwdb

```
#  - Generic input devices match:
#      evdev:input:bZZZZvYYYYpXXXXeWWWW-VVVV
#    This matches on the kernel modalias of the input-device, mainly:
#    ZZZZ is the bus-id (see /usr/include/linux/input.h BUS_*), YYYY, XXXX and
#    WWW are the 4-digit hex uppercase vendor, product and version ID and VVVV
#    is an arbitrary length input-modalias describing the device capabilities.
#    The vendor, product and version ID for a device node "eventX" is listed
# in /sys/class/input/eventX/device/id.
```

Command:

```
less /proc/bus/input/devices
```

Got this:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=05ac Product=0274 Version=0110
N: Name="Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-12/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.1/0003:05AC:0274.0004/input/input7
U: Uniq=D3H624316K1FTV4A63PS
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event7
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 0 0 0 1007b00011007 ff9f217ac14057ff ffbeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f
```

So Apple built-in keyboard is `evdev:input:b0003v05acp0274e0110*`

### 2. Get scancodes

I used `showkey --scancodes` in TTY to get a default map like this:

```
|           | scancode (hex) | keycode |
|-----------+----------------+---------|
| capslock  | 3a ba          |      58 |
|-----------+----------------+---------|
| fn        | -- --          |     464 |
| leftctrl  | 1d 9d          |      29 |
| leftalt   | 38 b8          |      56 |
| leftmeta  | e0 5b e0 db    |     125 |
|-----------+----------------+---------|
| rightctrl | e0 5c e0 dc    |     126 |
| rightalt  | e0 38 e0 b8    |     100 |
```

> I don't know why the `scancode` of all keys mentioned above are large than 1 byte...

### 3. Create config file in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/`

Create file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-apple-kb.hwdb` with following content:

```
evdev:input:b0003v05acp0274e0110*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_3aba=leftctrl
  KEYBOARD_KEY_1d9d=leftctrl
  KEYBOARD_KEY_38b8=leftmeta
  KEYBOARD_KEY_e05be0db=leftalt
  KEYBOARD_KEY_e05ce0dc=rightctrl
  KEYBOARD_KEY_e038e0b8=rightalt
```

Then reboot, not work...

> #### Update: use `evtest` to capture scancode.
>
> Take `Caps Lock` for example:
>
> ```
>  Event: time 1514827961.426158, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
>  Event: time 1514827961.538086, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70039
>  Event: time 1514827961.538086, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 58 (KEY_CAPSLOCK), value 0
>  Event: time 1514827961.538086, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
> ```
>
> So `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-apple-kb.hwdb` looks like this now:
>
> ```
> evdev:input:b0003v05acp0274e0110*
>   KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=leftctrl
>   KEYBOARD_KEY_700e0=leftctrl
>   KEYBOARD_KEY_700e2=leftmeta
>   KEYBOARD_KEY_700e3=leftalt
>   KEYBOARD_KEY_700e7=rightctrl
>   KEYBOARD_KEY_700e6=rightalt
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, not work either...

Also try to use `setkeycodes` like this, it said error:

```
$ sudo setkeycodes 3aba 29
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode 3aba to keycode 29: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument
```

Comment: those scancodes look odd.  does `evtest` show the same scancodes?  see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys#Scancodes

Comment: Still not work. I clone latest evtest from https://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/ and build + installed. I just updated the situation in question.

Comment: those codes from evdev look saner.  but your match line starts with a typo (`gevdev:input` should be `evdev:input`), hopefully this is just in the post?

Comment: Yes, sorry just in post. Now question was updated.

Comment: Did you run `systemd-hwdb update` and the other command shown in the "60-keyboard.hwdb" file?

Comment: There is also an article about this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes

Comment: I also tried this [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170048/21005)

Comment: Also [here](https://yulistic.gitlab.io/2017/12/linux-keymapping-with-udev-hwdb/) are detailed instructions.